To build of old project by newer Visual Studio CLI
How to solve build of one's old project by a newer Visual Studio non-GUI ie. MSVC build;
   C:\ext2fsd-code> msbuild Ext3Fsd.sln /p:Configuration=Release

    MSBuild version 17.12.12+1cce77968 for .NET Framework
    Build started 29-Dec-24 7:28:21 AM.
    MSBUILD : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.
    
    Build FAILED.
    MSBUILD : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing

in .sln file,
    Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
    # Visual Studio 2008
    Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Ext3Fsd", "Ext3Fsd\ext3fsd.vcproj", "{2328F787-71B4-408B-8E10-B7A95BF9A110}"
    EndProject
    Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Ext2Mgr", "Ext2Mgr\Ext2Mgr.vcproj", "{F0E304B5-AF20-49F7-8183-5994C6EA889D}"
    EndProject
    Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Ext2Srv", "Ext2Srv\Ext2Srv.vcproj", "{A18F670C-DA85-43F6-8620-99A2DD8CEF1A}"
    EndProject
    Global
            GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
                    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
                    SccProjectUniqueName0 = Ext3Fsd\\ext3fsd.vcproj
                    SccProjectName0 = Ext3Fsd
                    SccLocalPath0 = Ext3Fsd
                    SccProvider0 = MSSCCI:Perforce\u0020P4\u0020SCM
                    CanCheckoutShared = true
                    SccProjectUniqueName1 = Ext2Srv\\Ext2Srv.vcproj
                    SccProjectName1 = Ext2Srv
                    SccLocalPath1 = Ext2Srv
                    SccProvider1 = MSSCCI:Perforce\u0020P4\u0020SCM
                    CanCheckoutShared = true
            EndGlobalSection
            GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
                    Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
                    Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
            EndGlobalSection
            GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
                    {2328F787-71B4-408B-8E10-B7A95BF9A110}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = 

Debug|Win32
                    {2328F787-71B4-408B-8E10-B7A95BF9A110}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
                    {2328F787-71B4-408B-8E10-B7A95BF9A110}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
                    {2328F787-71B4-408B-8E10-B7A95BF9A110}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
                    {F0E304B5-AF20-49F7-8183-5994C6EA889D}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
                    {F0E304B5-AF20-49F7-8183-5994C6EA889D}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
                    {F0E304B5-AF20-49F7-8183-5994C6EA889D}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
                    {F0E304B5-AF20-49F7-8183-5994C6EA889D}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
                    {A18F670C-DA85-43F6-8620-99A2DD8CEF1A}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
                    {A18F670C-DA85-43F6-8620-99A2DD8CEF1A}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
                    {A18F670C-DA85-43F6-8620-99A2DD8CEF1A}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
                    {A18F670C-DA85-43F6-8620-99A2DD8CEF1A}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
            EndGlobalSection
            GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
                    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
            EndGlobalSection
    EndGlobal

To get notion let's look into its first vcproject file which's changed to UTF-8 from gb2312 and after put off some lines to succinct:
C:\ext2fsd-code>type Ext3Fsd/ext3fsd.vcproj
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VisualStudioProject
        ProjectType="Visual C++"
        Version="9.00"
        Name="Ext3Fsd"
        ProjectGUID="{2328F787-71B4-408B-8E10-B7A95BF9A110}"
        SccProjectName="Ext3Fsd"
        SccLocalPath="."
        SccProvider="MSSCCI:Perforce P4 SCM"
        Keyword="MakeFileProj"
        TargetFrameworkVersion="0"
        >
        <Platforms>
                <Platform
                        Name="Win32"
                />
        </Platforms>
        <ToolFiles>
        </ToolFiles>
        <Configurations>
                <Configuration
                        Name="Debug|Win32"
                        OutputDirectory=".\chk"
                        IntermediateDirectory=".\chk"
                        ConfigurationType="0"
                        InheritedPropertySheets="$(VCInstallDir)VCProjectDefaults\UpgradeFromVC60.vsprops"
                        UseOfMFC="0"
                        ATLMinimizesCRunTimeLibraryUsage="false"
                        >
                        <Tool
                                Name="VCNMakeTool"
                                BuildCommandLine=".\DDKBuild.bat -W7XP chk ."
                                ReBuildCommandLine=".\DDKBuild.bat -W7XP chk . -ceZ"
                                CleanCommandLine=""
                                Output="Ext2Fsd.sys"
                                PreprocessorDefinitions=""
                                IncludeSearchPath=""
                                ForcedIncludes=""
                                AssemblySearchPath=""
                                ForcedUsingAssemblies=""
                                CompileAsManaged=""
                        />
                </Configuration>
                <Configuration
                        Name="Release|Win32"
                        OutputDirectory=".\fre"
                        IntermediateDirectory=".\fre"
                        ConfigurationType="0"
                        InheritedPropertySheets="$(VCInstallDir)VCProjectDefaults\UpgradeFromVC60.vsprops"
                        UseOfMFC="0"
                        ATLMinimizesCRunTimeLibraryUsage="false"
                        >
                        <Tool
                                Name="VCNMakeTool"
                                BuildCommandLine=".\DDKBuild.bat -W7XP fre ."
                                ReBuildCommandLine=".\DDKBuild.bat -W7XP fre . -cZ"
                                CleanCommandLine=""
                                Output="Ext3Fsd.sys"
                                PreprocessorDefinitions=""
                                IncludeSearchPath=""
                                ForcedIncludes=""
                                AssemblySearchPath=""
                                ForcedUsingAssemblies=""
                                CompileAsManaged=""
                        />
                </Configuration>
        </Configurations>
        <References>
        </References>
        <Files>
                <Filter
                        Name="Source Files"
                        Filter="cpp;c;cxx;rc;def;r;odl;idl;hpj;bat"
                        >
                        <File
                                RelativePath="access.c"
                                >

                        <Filter
                                Name="nls"
                                >

                        </Filter>
                        <Filter
                                Name="ext4"            >
    
                        </Filter>
                        <Filter
                                Name="jbd"
                                >
         
                        </Filter>
                </Filter>
                <Filter
                        Name="Header Files"
                        Filter="h;hpp;hxx;hm;inl"
                        >
        
                        <Filter
                                Name="Linux"
                                >
                                <File
                                        RelativePath="include\linux\atomic.h">
                                <File
                                        RelativePath="include\linux\bitops.h"
      
                                </File>
                        </Filter>
                        <Filter
                                Name="asm"
                                >
       
                        </Filter>
                </Filter>
                <Filter
                        Name="Resource Files"
          
                </Filter>
                <Filter
                        Name="Douments"
                        >
            
                </Filter>
        </Files>
        <Globals>
        </Globals>
</VisualStudioProject>

Please help guide/point out why such error occurs, very gratified in advance

See "VCBuild vs. MSBuild: Build system changes in Visual Studio 2010". If you have access to VS2010 (e.g. if you have an MSDN subscription you can download old versions of Visual Studio), use VS2010 to convert the .vcproj files to .vcxproj files.

This CLI way can't do that (at least yet, AFAIK)  .
So to get the 'real' Microsoft Visual Studio IDE Version Community 2022, whose executable binary file name devenv launched, its wizard worked like a charm.
It'll immediately upgrade/update, migrate the old Visual Studio version project to the newest version.
One could compare the files .vcxproj and .vcproj remaining.

From looking at this document MSB4025, the error occurs  when MSBuild tries to load and parse a project, but the project file or MSBuild import file could not be loaded.
For this issue, please try the following:
1.From looking at your command  msbuild Ext3Fsd.sln,you are actually build the projects in the solution. Please open your project file (.vcproj ) and check it must be a valid XML MSBuild file.(e.g)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Project DefaultTargets="Build" 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  ...
</Project>

2.It's not obvious to figure out what files caused this issue, you can run the following command to rerun the build with full diagnostic logs.
msbuild Ext3Fsd.sln /p:Configuration=Release -verbosity:diag

3.Backup and then delete the vcproj.user file, then rebuild your projects.
4.Backup and  open the project in the latest version of Visual Studio(e.g:VS2022). Visual Studio offers to upgrade the project to the current schema. Then run the command to build the solution again.
For more information, please refer to Upgrade C++ projects from earlier versions of Visual Studio
